# Using JQuery to change HTML button image causes styling issues

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a standard HTML button which triggers some Ajax when pressed. I'm using JQuery to disable the button and display a progress GIF while I'm awaiting the return.

For some reason setting the background image of the button causes it to lose other styling and go out of alignment with its neighbours.

I've tried wrapping it in divs, setting all sorts of margins and positions and I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

FYI: I have no problem using `<input>` instead of `<button>` if that's easier.

**Broken:**

[image]

**Fixed:**

[image]

**Code:**

```js
var mybutton = $('#MyButton');

if (mybutton)
{
    mybutton.click(function() {

        // Disable
        mybutton.prop('disabled', true);
        
        // Hide text
        mybutton.html('');
        
        // Set image
        mybutton.css("background", "url('http://lorempixel.com/32/32/') no-repeat 32px center");
        
        // Wait 5 seconds to simulate slow Ajax return
        setTimeout(continueExecution, 3000);
    });
};

function continueExecution()
{
    // Reset button back to normal
    mybutton.html('Check');
    mybutton.css("background", "");
    mybutton.prop('disabled', false);
};
```

```css
#Label_Guid{
font-size: 20px;
}
#Textbox_Guid{
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#MyButton{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="Label_Guid">GUID:</span>
<input id="Textbox_Guid" type="text" name="guid">
<button id="MyButton">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is add the css to your button:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Your issue isn't coming from the background image, or the disable, it's because there is no content in the button. Without content, the default vertical alignment is changing its position.

Comment: Oh I see, so setting the button text to a space works as well. Genius. Why does it always have to be one line of easy code!? Thanks :-)

Comment: Any ideas about the background colour? I assume setting the image prevents all other painting so the button goes white/transparent.

Comment: You're right about the background color. You can only have one background going on for the element at any time, so it is ignoring all the button standard background styling because of your image. Put a div inside the button, with {height: 100%;}, and apply the background image to the div instead, and you should be on your way.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try that instead of editing the image to match the button, your way seems much better. Thanks again!